# remove default vertical centering for input text

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have a form and there are inputs on the form. I want to be able to control the positioning of the text inside the inputs. As you can see in the screenshot below, the input text is vertically centered by default. I want the input text to start from the top left of the input. I tried to achieve this by manipulating the padding like this:

```
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

This is not working. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: could you create a codepen Jevon?

Answer (score 1):

An `input` will always vertically align its content to the center.

Maybe a `<textarea>` can help you achieve that.

E.g.:

```html
<textarea placeholder="Type here" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Note: I'm not sure about how can it affect your form behavior, if it does.

Comment: I'm going to try this out. My concern is how it would affect the form behavior, as you have stated.